# Javascript - Delete all duplicates from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have problem with delete all duplicate in array.

> Array = [1,1,2,2,3]

Every solution, what I found, haves result this

> Array = [1,2,3]

But I need this

> Array = [3]

How can I do this?

Comment: Okay so you don't actually have a problem with the command. Delete duplicates deletes the duplicates which means that it will keep the original value. It does not mean it will delete everything related to a duplicate.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. If you literally googled 'deleting duplicates in array' you would have received a related 100 pages of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first iterate over the array once to obtain a `Map` of the frequencies of each item and then filter to find the elements that only appeared once.

```js
const arr = [1,1,2,2,3];
const freq = arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>(acc.set(curr,(acc.get(curr)||0)+1),acc),new Map);
const res = arr.filter(x => freq.get(x) === 1);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store an object for occurences of each element and get the elements that have the occurence of 1

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

const occurrences = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el] = (acc[el] || 0) + 1
  return acc
}, {})

const res = Object.entries(occurrences)
  .filter(([el, time]) => time === 1)
  .map(([el]) => +el)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some of the other solutions, this allows you to make a *single* loop over the array, rather than a `reduce` followed by a `filter` and/or `map` loop.  That said, there are trade-offs in readability and other condition checks, and it plays a bit fast and loose with the semantic intention of a `reduce`, so it might be a wash in terms of benefits.

```js
const myArray = [1,1,2,2,3];

const dupesRemoved = myArray.reduce((acc, cur, idx, src) => {
  if (!acc.dupes.has(cur)) {
    if (acc.singleInstances.has(cur)) {
      acc.singleInstances.delete(cur);
      acc.dupes.add(cur);
    } else {
      acc.singleInstances.add(cur);
    }
  }
  
  if (idx === src.length - 1) {
    return [...acc.singleInstances];
  }

  return acc;
}, { singleInstances: new Set(), dupes: new Set() });

console.log(dupesRemoved);
```

Comment: If you knew the values are only numbers, you could just use indexes to see if the holes of an array are set, and increment them if they are.

Comment: @HanYolo -- sounds interesting--- you might want to post that as its own answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and short solution:

```js
let arr = [1,1,2,2,3];  
let filtered_arr = arr.filter(v => arr.indexOf(v) === arr.lastIndexOf(v));
console.log(filtered_arr);
```